# Java ObjectInputStream only receives the last Object

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

If I'm writing two objects simultaneously to my `ObjectOutputStream` it causes the `ObjectInputStream` to receive the second object only without processing the first one. It's like the second message is overwriting the first message.

```
try
    {
        serverObjectWriter.writeObject(new Message("", this.getUsername() + " ist dem Chat beigetreten."));
        serverObjectWriter.flush();

        serverObjectWriter.writeObject(new Message(MessageType.CLIENT_JOINED, this.getUsername()));
        serverObjectWriter.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        ...
    }
```

So in this case I receive the second message only. I don't know what's happening with the first object though.
I've also tried to put those in separated Threads and send them in a synchronized way via the `join()` method.

Here's the part where I'm receiving the objects:

```
private class ServerHandler implements Runnable
{
    //
    Message message;

    @Override public void run()
    {
        try
        {   
            while((message = (Message) serverObjectReader.readObject()) != null)
            {
                switch(message.getMessageType())
                {
                case MESSAGE:
                    HPos pos;

                    if(message.getSender().equals(getUsername()))
                        pos = HPos.RIGHT;
                    else if(message.getSender().equals(""))
                        pos = HPos.CENTER;
                    else 
                        pos = HPos.LEFT;

                    Platform.runLater(() -> cgui.appendMessage(message.getSender(), message.getMessage(), message.getTime(), pos));
                    break;
                case CLIENT_JOINED:
                    Platform.runLater(() -> cgui.addClientToClientList(message.getMessage()));
                    break;
                case CLIENT_LEFT:
                    Platform.runLater(() -> cgui.removeClientFromClientList(message.getMessage()));
                    break;
                case CLIENT_CHANGED_USERNAME:
                    Platform.runLater(() -> cgui.renameClientFromClientList(message.getSender(), message.getMessage()));
                    break;
                case USERNAME_CHANGE_REQUEST:
                    setUsername(message.getMessage());
                    Platform.runLater(() -> cgui.getChatWindow().setTitle("Chat - " + getUsername()));
                    break;
                case CLIENT_TYPING:
                    break;
                case CLIENT_NOT_TYPING:
                    break;
                case CLIENT_SAW_MESSAGE:
                    break;
                }
            }
            Platform.runLater(() -> cgui.appendMessage("Die Verbindung zum Host wurde getrennt.", HPos.CENTER));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Platform.runLater(() -> cgui.appendMessage("Die Verbindung zum Host wurde getrennt.", HPos.CENTER));
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are setting the messageType for the first message and you have no `default` case for you `switch`

Comment: Did you try to place a breakpoint and verify that it is hit only once (inside the  run method)?

Comment: CraigR8806, the constructor sets it by default to MESSAGE.

Comment: efekctive, if I run this in debug mode and step forward through the thread it works fine for me (As wanted). Any suggestions now?

Comment: It might be useful to post your Message constructor in use

Comment: Your read loop is incorrect. `readObject()` doesn't return null at end of stream. It can return null any time you wrote a null. It throws `EOFException` at end of stream.

Comment: The Message class is not needed. The switch-case block is NOT the source of my problem. It's the part where I'm sending two objects simultaneously as written.